# Create and read an XML file

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql

We must create an XML file with invoices information for government e-books. Then we must upload it and take back a response.
For now, I create an XML file from a select query:

```
SELECT invoiceNr, invoiceDate FROM invoiceHeader 
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT  
        lineNumber, netValue, vatCategory
        FROM invoiceDetails 
        WHERE invoiceDetails.headid = invoiceHeader.unid FOR XML PATH('invoiceDetails')
    ) XmlinvoiceDetails(invoiceDetails)
FRO XML PATH('invoice'), root('invoicedoc')
```

and using `SQLDataReader` and `StreamWriter` we are saving XML on disk.

Then, with `WebRequest`, we upload the XML file and get a response back as an XML file. That file (response.xml) has a sequential number 1,2,3 e.t.c. with information (success or not) for every invoice node, we upload.

First of all, I need to know if there is another way of creating an XML file, more efficient because in XML file we will have many invoices and we want very quickly to create an XML file.
Second, we want to find a way of updating records we have exported in the XML file, perhaps with unique index because we want to know every record in which XML file has been exported and with which order or in which XML line node has been written, in order getting the response.xml with the results to update each record with the status code (success or not).

We need your opinion, and, of course, we need to know the most efficient way to do this because there are millions of records.

Comment: The most efficient way to generate XML files from MS SQL Server is by using bcp.

Comment: Thank you for your response, do you mean SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "select * ......

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to call SQL Server **bcp** utility and generate XML file on the file system.
It is preferably to package your XML generating T-SQL as a stored procedure with parameters. This way it is easier to test and maintain it.

If there is a need, it is possible to launch almost the same code in c# via `Process.Start(...)` API call.

**SQL**

```
/*
-T tells BCP to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server. It will operate as the user/account who's running the command.
-U <login_id> -P <password> tells BCP to use SQL Server account while connecting to SQL Server.
*/
DECLARE @SQLCmd VARCHAR(8000)
   , @outputFileName VARCHAR(256) = 'e:\Temp\SSIS_help15.xml'
   , @bcp VARCHAR(256) = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
   , @SQL VARCHAR(2048) = 'EXEC dbname.dbo.usp_GenerateXML;'
   , @tcpPort VARCHAR(10) = '1433'
   , @WindowsAuth BIT = 1   -- 1 is for Windows Authentication, 0 is for SQL Server Authentication
   , @loginID VARCHAR(100) = 'loginID'
   , @password VARCHAR(100) = 'password'
   , @serverName VARCHAR(100) = 'SPACESHIP';

-- /B "WindowTitle" parameters produce output in the SSSMS !!!
SET @SQLCmd = 'START /B "WindowTitle" "' + @bcp + '"' 
            + ' "' + @SQL + '"' 
            + ' queryout "' + @outputFileName + '"'
            --+ IIF(@WindowsAuth = 1, ' -T', ' -U '+ @loginID + ' -P ' + @password)
            + CASE WHEN @WindowsAuth = 1 THEN ' -T'
               ELSE ' -U '+ @loginID + ' -P ' + @password
               END
            + ' -c -C 65001 -a 32768'
            + ' -S "' + @serverName + ',' + @tcpPort + '"';

-- just to see it
SELECT @SQLCmd AS [Command to execute];

-- create file on the file system
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. 
I need a little more help. I have created classes for XML schema and I want to know if there is a way to load immediately SQL query into those classes in once and not loop through all rows to built XML. 
I need to know if there is a way to link dataset with XML classes, in which every datatable of the dataset is (typeof) every XML class.

Comment: @gg2007mva, IMHO I answered your original question on what is the most efficient way to generate XML files from a database.